# RL exception in launching moveIt

Tags: moveit, ros-melodic, roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to launch jaco arm in moveit using the command

```
roslaunch j2n6s300_moveit_config j2n6s300_jaco_lfd.launch
```

but getting this error

```
RLException: [j2n6s300_jaco_lfd.launch] is neither a launch file in package [j2n6s300_moveit_config] nor is [j2n6s300_moveit_config] a launch file name
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
akashleena@akashleena-Latitude-3490:~/catkin_ws/src/jaco_con
```

I have already done `source devel/setup.bash` still getting the error. Please help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/349219/rl-exception-in-launching-moveit/) by [aleena_infinitynbeyond](https://answers.ros.org/users/44647/aleena_infinitynbeyond/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2020-04-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you  check if your package "j2n6s300_moveit_config" has a launch file "j2n6s300_jaco_lfd.launch" ?

---

Originally posted by [medashan](https://answers.ros.org/users/41982/medashan/) with karma: 16 on 2021-06-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0